# Spamassassin custom rules not applying to Outlook emails

Tags: perl, spamassassin

I have several custom rules on my `local.cf` file set, and one is about bit.ly links. I've set it so it gives 3 points to every email that contains "bit.ly" inside their body, but in some emails works and in others don't.

This happens on outlook.com and live.com emails, so spammers can get around it and bypass this rules.

I'm using EFA's project with MailScanner and SpamAssassin (version 3.4.1 running on Perl version 5.10.1).

The rule I'm using is the following:

```
body bitly_fucking_final_rule /bit.ly/i
score bitly_fucking_final_rule 3.0
describe bitly_fucking_final_rule Bitly rule for testing purposes
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does you perl script look like?

Comment: The point is not about Perl itself, but within Spamassassin. It gets the rules I write on the local.cf file and applies it over the emails, but on some emails work, and in other ones don't. Kind of like Apache decides to take those rules in whenever it wants, and sometimes don't even.

Answer (score 0):

The command "body" will not work, use "uri" or "rawbody" instead.

Example:

```
uri LOCAL_BITLY_RULE /bit\.ly/i
score LOCAL_BITLY_RULE 3.0
describe LOCAL_BITLY_RULE Mails with Bitly links are often spam
```

Please remember to test your local rules using the command:

```
spamassassin --lint
```